# Saving image with Date and Time

Tags: c#, image, datetime

I am trying to save image captured from web cam with current time.Like

`06.06.2010 22:29:52.jpg`

But compiler does not allow time format 22:20:30 . I searched but I could not find how to write time like 22.29.59 or how can solve this problem ?

```
String photoTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
String SuspiciousPath = Path.Combine(PhotoPath+"//suspicious",photoTime+".jpg");
FirstPersonTestImage.Save(SuspiciousPath);
```

Comment: please don't duplicate a tag ("C#") both in the title and in the tags. Also, please don't use "Hi", and "Thanks". This is a Q&A site, and we're not having a conversation.

Comment: Hi was for be polite.OK wont be next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH.mm.ss");`

See full documentation in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

I recommend `DateTime.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd.HH_mm_ss");` so you can sort by filename and it sorts by time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom format string, like this:

```
String photoTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy HH.mm.ss");
```

However, I recommend that you use a sortable format, like this:

```
String photoTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH.mm.ss");
```

These strings will sort by timestamp.